# Amazon S3 rewrote uploaded PDF names with "+" in the filename as "%2B", can't access them from nginx server

Tags: wordpress, nginx, pdf, amazon-s3

I'm using [S3 Uploads](https://github.com/humanmade/S3-Uploads) to offload my WordPress Media Library to an S3 bucket. I used the AWS CLI to bulk migrate my local Media Files to the S3 bucket. So far so good.

Some of the existing PDFs in my library had "+" in the filename, example "mypdf+_name.pdf". When uploaded to S3, the object name was changed to "mypdf%2B_name.pdf". According to [this thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=55746), this seems to be a long-running thing.

I tried to set up an nginx config to rewrite anything in my WordPress Media Library that has a "+" in it to go to the corrected S3 URL:

```
location ~ "^/wp-content/uploads/(.*)$" {
    location ~ "^/wp-content/uploads/(.*)\+(.*)$" {
        rewrite "^/wp-content/uploads/(.*)\+(.*)$" "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/mybucket/uploads/$1%2B$2" redirect;
    }
}
```

This seems to perform the requested redirect, except the "+" is not getting rewritten as "%2B".

For example, "http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/mypdf+_name.pdf" gets redirected to "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/mybucket/uploads/2013/10/mypdf+_name.pdf". This returns an "AccessDenied" error from S3; when I manually change the "+" to "%2B" in the URL bar, my file displays as expected.

To test if there wasn't something else wrong with my configuration, I changed the redirect to some nonsense, keeping the "%2B":

```
location ~ "^/wp-content/uploads/(.*)$" {
    location ~ "^/wp-content/uploads/(.*)\+(.*)$" {
        rewrite "^/wp-content/uploads/(.*)\+(.*)$" "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/mybucket/uploads/$1%2B$2blahblahblah" redirect;
    }
}
```

This results in "http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/mypdf+_name.pdf" -> "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/mybucket/uploads/2013/10/mypdf+_name.pdfblahblahblah"

So my redirect is "working", but something along the way is choosing to keep "+" instead of translating it to "%2B".

How can I make nginx redirect my file to the correct URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what ended up working for me:

```
location ~ "^/wp-content/uploads/(.*)\+(.*)$" {
    if ($request_uri ~ "^/wp-content/uploads/(.*)\+(.*)$"){
        set $modified_uri "/$1%2B$2";
        return 302 https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/mybucket/uploads$modified_uri;
    }
}
```

If anyone sees an obvious problem with this let me know. I know I've read using if blocks inside a location is bad but the [documentation](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) indicates using a `return` directive is kosher so I'm rolling with it for now.